# multiple comboboxes in windows application in .net

Tags: windows, combobox

I have been working in asp.net application since start my job. but situation is, i am working in windows application now a days.

I have situation that, on my windows application form I want to show  Country,state,city combo boxes.

so that when i select the country , its state must be filled up in state combo box, same for the city as usual.

Some how i have created the scenario in asp.net. as 
On form/page load event i have filled Country combobox. in selected index changed event of country combo box, I am filling states of selected country in state combobox, where as in selected index changed event of state i am filling cities of selected state, in city combobox.

how to achieve this scenario in windows application ?
. please guide me i am new in windows.

Comment: Please reword this, it is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up different id's to each combobox? Perhaps the onChange event handler considers all combobox to be the same, which is why your page is reloading each time. Try to differentiate each input item so that the method that updates contents for each of them know what it's doing.

Regards!

Comment: Yes I have settled up different id's to each combobox. and i think framework can not accept same control name's or id on single form. well thanks for reply.